# migrating DB2 data to oracle using SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, migration, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to migrate data from DB2 UDB to Oracle database. Migration works fine for most of the schemas of that database except for those schemas that have the same table name in that schema. For example if my schema name is foo and I have a table named foo in that schema, during migration the schema name is converted into foo_ (foo suffixed by underscore)

any ideas on how to get around this problem?

Comment: You haven't specified what result you want to achieve. What is wrong with making a `foo_` table? What did you want it to do instead?

Comment: Problem is the _1 is added to the schema not the table so after migration I cannot rename an Oracle Schema/User.